# how to save json value in trigger

Tags: mysql, json, triggers

we create a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER `insert_category` AFTER INSERT ON `cleaner_service`
 FOR EACH ROW UPDATE users
  SET user_category = (select group_concat(concat(service_id) SEPARATOR '-') from cleaner_service where users.id=cleaner_service.user_id)
WHERE users.id=NEW.user_id
```

it store value like **8-7-9** this i would like to store this value in json **["1","2","3"]** can you tell me how to do that in **MYSQL**

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
SET user_category = concat("[",(select group_concat(concat(service_id) SEPARATOR ','),"]") from cleaner_service where users.id=cleaner_service.user_id)
```